# Install Two Network Adapter Drivers Side by Side

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I need to install CommView for WiFi on my computer, but the problem is that the replacement driver for my network adapter card that allows it to work with CommView for WiFi overwrites the original driver for my card. This is a problem because the original driver for my card has some features that make it integrate better with my computer, and the CommView for WiFi driver does not have these features, and as a result, connecting to the internet is often a struggle. I would like to remedy this issue by installing the two drivers side by side, switching between which one the adapter is using as needed. Is this possible and how would I do it?

Comment: what OS are you on? most will not allow such an operation, because the interfaces between the kernel, the driver loaded, and the actual IO device are designed to be loaded once and unloaded once, per boot, and does not expect them to be swapped, for a host of reasons, including obtaining exclusive access to the device. On linux you could probably come up with ways to load and unload via scripts, but I would expect doing this regularly would be rather unstable.

Comment: @FrankThomas I am using Windows 8.1 Pro.